# Mass swinging in a horizontal circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

> A mass of $100$ grams is tied to a $50 cm$ long string(secured to the ceiling). The mass swings around in an horizontal circle with a constant speed and it performs a quarter of circle every second. What's the tension of the string and its angle with respect to the horizontal axis?

[image: Mass swinging]

So the problem gives me this data:

- **mass** : 0,1 *kg*
- **string length** : 0.5 *m*
- **angular speed** : $\frac{\pi}{2}rads^{-1}$

I can find the weight($g = 9.8 ms^{-2}$):

- **weight** : 0.98 *N*

Now I don't know how to find the tension and angle using only this data. I've seen similar problem and they usually give you already the tension or the angle of the string.

Comment: Draw the free body diagram at first ... Identify which forces are working ...

Comment: If you are in doubt of where to start, always try to think of some equation/formula were *what you are looking for* is included. And then start from there. Here, you are looking for the force of string tension - this only appears in Newton's laws. So set up one of Newton's laws either vertically or horizontally (you will need to make a force diagram in order to have the correct forces plugged into Newton's law). Then look at what more is needed (what else is unknown), and think of new equations/formulae where they are included. Step by step you will get closer and closer until you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the tension in the string be **T**. Then clearly for the horizontal plane, the component of **T** along the radius provides the required inward (centripetal) force.

If you assume the angle marked in the figure to be $\theta$, then

**T**$ cos\theta = m*\omega ^2 * r$

Here, $r = $ (string length)*$cos\theta$

Hence, $$T = m*\omega^2*l$$where $l$ is the string length. I hope you can take it from here.